# The OAuth client was not found when tried to implement login with Google plus in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, google-api-php-client, hybridauth

I have tried to login with Google plus API but it is showing error.

My redirect URL -http://himanshustorymob.com/gauth/auth?hauth.done=Google

I have also changed the product name but still it is showing same error.

```
My google_auth.php has this code            

 'Google' => array (
 "enabled" => true,
'keys'=>array('id'=>" ",'secret'=>" " ),
'scope'=>"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"token_uri"=>"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")));
```

My Controller has this function

```
  public function gauth($auth=NULL)

{
    if ($auth == 'auth') {
        try {
            Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return Redirect::to('login');

        }
        return;
    }


    $oauth = new Hybrid_Auth(app_path() . '/config/google_auth.php');

    $providers = $oauth->authenticate('Google');

    $user_profile = $providers->getUserProfile();


}
```

I am using Hybrid auth package.

I have changed product name several time redirect URL also but showing same error.
Please help me out .What to do now

Comment: What is the error message exactly saying?

Comment: @martinweise client name is invalid